# Сортировка по дате без учёта времени

Tags: mysql

Как в *MySQL* сделать сортировку до дате без учёта времени. Например у нас есть даты:

```
2015-02-12 10:01:02

2015-02-12 23:01:02

2015-01-12 23:01:02
```

Я нашёл только такой запрос, но он сортирует по дате без учёта года и месяца:

```
SELECT * FROM news OREDER BY DAY(date), views
```

Мне нужно, чтоб время при сортировке не учитывалось, так как сортировка будет по количеству просмотров по каждому дню. 
Как вариант, я нашёл такое решение, но может есть что-то попроще:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS sort_date FROM news ORDER BY sort_date, views
```

Comment: Чем вам не угодил вариант с форматированием? И так же проще некуда

Answer (score 7, accepted):

функция `day()` — это [день месяца](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day).

вам же нужна дата. которая вычисляется, например, [функцией `date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

например, так:

```
select * from news order by date(date), views
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я искал

Comment: @dima-opr, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).